# Grails and Spring Security CAS plugin

Tags: spring, grails

I am currently having an issue where when I try to start my app I get the error:

```
ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Cannot execute      
null+null
Message: Cannot execute null+null
```

This only happens when I tell the program to compile the Spring Security CAS plugin. This only started happening when I turned off forking, since it was making it hard to set up a JNDI. Is there a way to fix this problem without turning back on forking?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the reason it wasn't working was because I hadn't finished configuring it. This doesn't make much sense to me, given that I was able to run the app just fine before without configuring it, seeing as how I never used that plugin within the implementation, it was just downloaded.